# How to make jQuery condition?

Tags: jquery

I am doing a slide show, for that i am checking the slide number. there two options show and hide, for that i wrote this condition. is this correct ? not it's through the error.

```
 var onSlide_ag = (onSlide_ag == 1) ? $('id="a_prev"').hide() : $('id="a_prev"').show();
```

any one correct it? or let me know the mistake with i did..?

This is actually need to use in the  if conditions, but i used the short way to make this out put.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
 var onSlide_ag = (onSlide_ag == 1) ? $('#a_prev').hide() : $('#a_prev').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is incorrect. Use `$('#a_prev')` instead of `$('id="a_prev"')`.

The jQuery page has [a list of all selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), where the ID and class selectors are most used.

Answer (score 2):

To select an element with a given id you have to use `#`:

```
var onSlide_ag = (onSlide_ag == 1) ? $('#a_prev').hide() : $('#a_prev').show();
```